# When USB-C external monitor sleeps, it cuts connections to its USB hub (late-2016 MacBook Pro)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I have an LG UD88 monitor, which is 4K and connects over USB-C to my new MacBook Pro. I love it—except for a couple of issues, one of which is that when my MBP puts the display to sleep, any devices connected to the USB 3.0 hub get disconnected—like external drives—without being ejected. Bad news.

I feel like there must be an easy solution to this that I'm missing—after all, this monitor has been out for half a year now, and the whole point of USB-C is that all of these things work over a single cable. But I can't find a setting in the monitor menu (and no updated firmware AFAIK) that would seem to address this.

One workaround, I guess, would be to simply set "Turn display off after" to "Never" in Energy Saver, but this seems pretty inelegant. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Same issue here. This is pretty dumb as it prevents Time Machine from doing backups and could potentionaly corrupt disk data (I always get the warning that disk wasn't ejected properly after waking up)